# How i can search in many tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to do a search in many tables with a

```
<input type="text" name="search" />

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars,people,cities WHERE 
cars.reg= '$search' || people.phone = '$search' || city.address = '$search'");
```

Is it possible to do that? any suggestions for that a DB search with PHP?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a UNION ALL query

```
SELECT name as findValue,
'cars' as tableName
FROM cars 
where cars.name = "$search"
UNION ALL
SELECT name as findValue,
'people' as tableName
FROM people
where people.name = "$search"
UNION ALL
SELECT city as findValue,
'cities' as tableName
FROM cities 
where cities .name = "$search"
```

It's important that you return the same type of field from all the subqueries. Read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) for more info, basically the idea is that you return a UNION of all data found from the queries.

Comment: If you also need to see the source of each row in the result, you can add a static field to each union. For example "Cars" as source, "People" as source, "Cities" as Source

Comment: @jmacinnes yes of course so that you know where does the data come from